Does the axis of spin of a particle also rotate?
As a physics enthusiast, I would like to ask about the following curiosities:
Particles (that I understand as excitation in a "field") have this property called spin. I would like to ask whether the axis of spin is also systematically rotating, and if yes, at what kind of frequency and with what type of trajectory?
In the case of 2 particles being entangled (I guess that means they essentially become a "unique" wave (?) ), if the spin axes do also rotate, would they rotate with a different phase or trajectory, or would they be the same? If yes, I would like some references to read about that.

The behavior of the axis of angular momentum is more complicated than you are thinking.
Because of the uncertainty principle, an electron doesn't have a precise trajectory. At any time, there is a range of positions where it is likely to be if you measure its position. There is a range of momenta it is likely to have if you measure that. Depending on the state, you can trace an approximate trajectory. But you can't determine it exactly like you can in classical physics.
Likewise, an electron doesn't have a precise angular momentum vector. It has an intrinsic spin, which is to say an intrinsic angular momentum. You can measure the magnitude of the angular momentum. You can choose an axis and measure the component of angular momentum along that axis. But you cannot measure the component along multiple axes at the same time. So you cannot fully determine the direction the angular momentum vector is pointing. You can know some information about it.
Angular momentum is quantized. If you choose an axis and measure the component of angular momentum along that axis, you always get one of two values. Either the electron's angular momentum is $45^o$ from being parallel to the axis or $45^o$ from being anti-parallel to it. We call these states spin up and spin down.
An electron in an atom also has angular momentum from "orbiting" around the nucleus. There is no classical trajectory, so the orbit isn't like a planet going around the sun. Never the less, it is called orbital angular momentum. This too is quantized, though there can be more than two states. You can add orbital angular momentum and spin to get total angular momentum of the electron.
An atom has many electrons. Usually about as many electrons are spin up as spin down. Likewise electrons arrange themselves so about as many orbital angular momenta are up as down. So the total for the atom is small. So even though you can't fully determine the direction of angular momentum, electrons can arrange themselves in more or less opposite directions.
It is possible to entangle two electrons so the total angular momentum is $0$. Both electrons are in a superposition of spin up and spin down. If you measure both electrons, you will find that one is spin up and the other spin down. Though before you measure, it is not possible to say which is spin up or spin down. If you measure one, you know the value you will get for the other before you measure.
It is possible to send the electrons flying far apart. Now you get one of the weirdest things in quantum mechanics. You can measure both at the same time. The instant before you measure, both are in a superposition and neither is spin or or spin down. Experiments can show that spin state of each is not set before they are measured.
The instant after you measure, one is spin up and the other is spin down. The measurements can be so close to the same time that light does not have time to get from one to the other. So nothing travels from one electron to tell the other which spin state it took on.
They don't know ahead of time what state they will be in. They don't coordinate with each other. Yet they always wind up opposite.
This is called the Einstein–Podolsky–Rosen paradox or EPR paradox. They thought this was proof that quantum mechanics was not a complete description of nature. But it turned out that it is. Nature is just stranger than one might expect.

A spinning electron is a tiny magnet. Atoms where angular momenta of electrons don't totally cancel are bigger tiny magnets. Iron is such an atom. Cobalt is another.
Atoms group together to form crystals. In an iron crystal, neighboring atoms line up so their angular momenta are more or less parallel. The magnetic fields add together. An iron crystal is a magnet. Iron crystals are usually microscopic. In a piece of iron, they align in random directions. So iron is usually not a magnet. It is possible to align them so iron makes a magnet.
In a cobalt crystal, neighboring atoms line up so the angular momenta and magnetic fields cancel. Cobalt is anti-ferromagnetic. You cannot make a magnet out of pure cobalt.
Veritasium and Minute Physics made a video on this. MAGNETS: How Do They Work?

Thank you mmesser for the enlightening answer! I will have to re-read it several times to digest it :-) I hear a lot of those expressions like "both are in a superposition and neither is spin or spin down". Since everything seems to be so fuzzy, how do we know that this "superposition" is not just a result of a "very fast" (say one at each plank time or whatever) orientation "switching" of the spin axis? Could it be or does the theory categorically exclude it?

This might help. It explains superposition of states on its way to something else - Parallel Worlds Probably Exist. Here’s Why

You try to be pedagogic. However, it is not necessary to talk about many particles to answer the question. EPR is not relevant, ferro- and antiferromagentism is not relevant, nuclei and the analogy to the sun is not relevant. Only first 3 paragraphs are informative. Let me emphasise, any discussion about a spin state makes no sense if the very notion of spin state is not given.

Particle spin can precess due to applied torque from an external field.
For separated entangled particles, nothing you do to one of the pair has any effect on the other. It only affects correlations between measurements of their properties. Precession of one of the particles' spins has the same effect on the correlation as rotating the measurement apparatus for that particle's spin.

Thank you, John. It is very interesting. I am going to read that.

Your answer is not rigourous. You refer to "separated entangled particles" without defining what "separated" and "entangled" means. Moreover, "spin precession" is a jargon. A proper way would be to refer to expectation values of spin operators.

@yarchik Precession is a commonly used model. There's no reason to obfuscate it with excessive abstraction. In an experiment, it is certainly clear what "separated" means. Again, there no need for excessive abstraction.

Thank you, yarchik. One is never rigorous enough, especially when conceptually tough problems are involved :-) About the superposition, how do we know that a particle is really doing that if we cannot observe such a superposition and we can only observe either of two states. Could it not be that, instead of being in a "superposition," the particle is simply deterministically switching continuously between the 2 states (like a sort of vibration) ?

@Jada What experiment could test your hypothesis? Many have been tried...

@jada Rigorous math often leads to physical nonsense, e.g. the Banach-Tarski construction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox). Physics is disciplined by experiments, not rigorous reasoning. There is no substitute for that discipline. Mathematical rigor is neither necessary nor sufficient.

@JohnDoty I have no idea at the moment. But I could reverse the question. Do experiments confirm that there is actual "superposition" and not that, for instance, the axis is continuously switching ("vibrating") more deterministically between the 2 final states? (If not, it would seem to me that removing the superposition, by Occam's razor, might even help solve other fundamental conceptual problems).

@Jada No experiment can ever confirm that there is actual superposition, because no experiment can ever confirm that any mathematical abstraction actually exists. All we can do is test models, and superposition has proven to be an excellent model for what happens in reality.
